# Write data to a file using CGI-perl

Tags: perl

I have a problem in writing data to a file using CGI. the code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI ":standard";

print "Content-type:text/html \n\n";

open (FILE, '>', "file.txt") or die ("Could not open the file for writing...$!");
print FILE "something";
close(FILE);
```

The above code is giving the following error:
"Could not open the file for writing...Permission denied at /var/www/cgi-bin/wfile.cgi line 8. 
The read and write permission for the file is already set... Please help!!!

Comment: for the `www-user` as well? The directory permissions too?

Comment: "The read and write permission for the file is already set" — to what? And what user does the web server run the script as?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The perl script will run as the user that apache/httpd/whatever is running as. You need to make sure that the directory and file is writeable by that user. Why not try writing to `/tmp/` first.

Comment: Yes, the best approach is a step-by-ste one, here... The problem is probably the lack for http server user permissions to write to that file... Unfortunately the methods to detect the http server user name depends on linux distribution, which is not specified in the question...

Comment: Yes.. its working now... but is it possible to redirect it to a file in another directory...?

Comment: Of course, you're specifying which file to open in your `open()` call.